# I want to use Ubuntu features available in windows 10 to setup PHP project.

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I am using windows 10, I want to use ubuntu that coming with windows 10 to install all tools as laragon or wamp, IDE like phpStorm and web browser like google chrome.
I search on google, I find some commands for installation of some features like
For Apache2 : sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils
      starting:  service apache2 start

For google-chrome : sudo apt install chromium-browser
I can't open chrome via command line.

For Postgres : sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib

1. Can I use this feature to do all of those staffs?
2. if yes how/where should I put my project files?
3. can I mix some windows features with Ubuntu, say apache server in ubuntu and use web browser in window?

Comment: What is `git bush`?

Comment: bash.exe for command

Comment: Please clean up your question then, say bash if you mean bash, and not bush. Please show the actual commands you executed to get the output in that screenshot.